# Can't add value into Dictionary containing dictionaries of dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, float>>> CPUResults = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, float>>>();
```

Now, I'd like to add some data:

```
CPUResults.Add("KEY 1", new Dictionary<string, Dictionary <DateTime, float>>().Add("key 1", new Dictionary<DateTime,float>()));
```

Actually, i don't want my keys to be: key 1, key 2, etc. - just not to complicate I named those keys like this.

Well, important thing is, this won't compile. I have no idea what I did wrong - it took me a while to come up with this, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Well `Add` has a `void` return type... so what do you think you're passing as the second argument to the outer `Add` call?

Comment: You're right, now i get it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add` method doesn't return the dictionary. Instead, initialize the inner dictionary like this:

```
CPUResults.Add(
    "KEY 1",
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary <DateTime, float>>
    {
        { "key 1", new Dictionary<DateTime,float>() } 
    });
```